# Show that $\arctan x=x^2$ has exactly one strictly positive solution

Tags: trigonometry

How can I show that $\arctan x=x^2$ has exactly one solution in $\Bbb R^+$?

Comment: $0$ is not a positive number.

Comment: @IanMiller I know, but it does answer the first question: "Show that atleast one solution exists".

Comment: For the first bit sure but thats the easy part of the question.

Comment: @IanMiller Agreed, removed it from the question.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987478/knowing-which-theorem-of-calculus-to-use-to-prove-number-nature-of-solutions/)

Comment: @Smebbs is my answer what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2-arctan(x)$.

$0\;$  is a root .

by intermediate value theorem we check easily that there is a root in $
I=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},1)$.

$ f$ is continuous at $I$,

$f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})<0$,
 and

$f(1)>0$.

assume there are two roots $a$ and $b$ such that $0<a<b$.

then the numerator of $f'(x)$ which is

$g(x)=2x^3+2x-1$, will have two roots

$c$ and $d$ such that

$0<c<a<d<b$ using Role's theorem.

and $g'(x)$ will have a root between $c$ and $d$.

but

$\forall x\in \mathbb R \;\; g'(x)=2(3x^2+1)>0$

that is the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Try to differentiate $\mathrm{arctan} (x)-x^2$ and use the mean value theorem.